# Alignment of expanding view in Relative Layout

Tags: android

I got three images of a frame, left , mid and right. The left and right are normal images which i give as wrap content. The center one is a patched image that can expand horizontally. I need to use relative layout to align them. But the center image must not have fix size(as it expands horizontally). I can do it using linear layout by following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cD"
        android:src="@drawable/l_left_corner" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/l_vertical_streatch"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cD" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cD"
        android:src="@drawable/l_right_corner" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do the same in relative layout(if possible, in frame layout too)?

Edit: My full layout (with nested weights)

http://pastie.org/8469454#1-2

Comment: you don't need to use `RelativeLayout`. you can implement this via `LinearLayout` too.

Comment: Actually i have many other things in my layout. So, I have to use nested weights which is bad for performance. I am posting code of the full layout above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code, just switch 40dp from my left and right ImageViews to wrap_content when you use some real image.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_left"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_left"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image_right"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_right"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the result: [image: relative layout]

Comment: Nice answer, to the point. Just place the center image code to thebottom of right image code. Other wise, error occurs.

Comment: hmmm.. it's quite strange since it works perfectly in AndroidStudio :)

Comment: in eclipse, it is showing error: cannot find resource "image_right"